# Overlay Calendar switching between Weekly and Monthly views

Tags: list-view, calendar, sharepoint-calendar

I've got an Calendar with a number of views and overlays. The default is set to a weekly view and I've been asked to provide a way to switch between a weekly and monthly view. Is there a way of doing this.

Comment: You can do it from ribbon -> calendar tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switching between weekly and monthly view is available from the ribbon (Calendar tab, Scope section).

Please see the following screenshots (month and week view):

[image: Month view]

[image: Week view]

**Update:**

In order to change views (between month, day, week) without using the ribbon, i will suggest the following options:

Using Javascript

The following functions are responsible for this:

```
<input name="Week" type="button" value="Week" onclick="javascript:MoveView('week');  />
<input name="Day" type="button" value="Day" onclick="javascript:MoveView('day');  />
<input name="Month" type="button" value="Month" onclick="javascript:MoveView('month');  />
```

A "no-code" solution:

Add the following endings to your initial URL in order to change views:

/?CalendarPeriod=day

/?CalendarPeriod=week

/?CalendarPeriod=month

For example, the URL https://server/Lists/TestCal/calendar.aspx/?CalendarPeriod=day will switch the view to day an so on.

Comment: Cheers, Is there a way for a user to switch views without using the ribbon?

Comment: I will suggest using javascript.
The following functions are responsible for this: 
MoveView('day'); for Day View,  
MoveView('month'); for Month View,  
MoveView('week'); for Week View.  
Try it via browser console.

Comment: Also you can add the following endings to your initial URL in order to change views: 
/?CalendarPeriod=day, /?CalendarPeriod=week, /?CalendarPeriod=month. For example, https://server/Lists/TestCal/calendar.aspx/?CalendarPeriod=day will switch the view to day an so on.

Comment: Cheers that works!

Comment: Hi, I've updated my initial answer, please mark it as good answer if you're satisfied, thanks.